# Grok pattern for graylog

Tags: design-patterns, grok, graylog2

I'm retreiving data that I want to analyze with Graylog.

The data looks like below,

```
[{"tag":"DO_SIMU[199].1","value":"False","time":"2018-09-05T14:35:09.1189226+02:00"}]
[{"tag":"DO_SIMU[199].2","value":"True","time":"2018-10-05T14:35:09.1189226+02:00"}]
[{"tag":"asefsfdfsd","value":"135","time":"2018-09-05T14:35:09.1189226+02:00"}]
[{"tag":"tit.1","value":"152.551","time":"2018-09-05T14:35:09.1189226+02:00"}]
[{"tag":"DO_SIMU[1].2551","value":"False","time":"6454-09-05T14:35:09.1189226+02:00"}]
[{"tag":"kfmdsfsmdlf.i1","value":"maman","time":"2018-09-05T14:35:09.1189226+15:251"}]
```

I have to create for each line a variable called with the value of tag (DO_SIMU[199].1 or kfmdsfsmdlf.i1 for example) and to put in this value the value of `value`

This last step seems to be easy with json,

So I'm looking for create a grok pattern that just return me something like

```
{"DO_SIMU[199].1":"False"}
```

excluding all the rest.

If somebody has a idea, I thank him in advance.

Comment: I just see that the first character of the output is "[". Of course, the right one is "{".

Comment: What about this entry:
[{"tag":"asefsfdfsd","value":"135","time":"2018-09-05T14:35:09.1189226+02:00"}]

I recommend you to try grok debugger, after this maybe you can write a more precise question.

Comment: Why the way, which pattern are you using right now?